# How to apply a function to existing second elements in dataframe column with not getting IndexError from elements that do not have a second element?

Tags: python, range, list-comprehension

I have a data frame where certain columns have two elements divided by "/".
"gasoline/electric" under the "fuel" column, for example.

However, not all elements inside the columns have two elements. Some are just "gasoline" with no second element.

- When I apply my formula below searching for the [0] position all is swell.
- When I set it for the [1] position, it returns Index Error: list index out of range.

Is there a way I can use my code below with, map inside a list compression line while avoiding this error?

I have tried creating a separate dataframe with just the rows that have two elements.

This works but I would like to learn if there is a way to do all this without creating a separate daraframe and keeping all my rows together in a single dataframe.

See below and thanks.

```py
split_columns = ['fuel','city_mpg','hwy_mpg','cmb_mpg']

divide=lambda x:x.split("/")[1]

result1=[(list(map(divide, df_18[c]))) for c in split_columns]

print(result1)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to modify your code as follows:

```
divide = lambda x: x.split("/")[1] if "/" in x else ""
```